# Comparison between solubility of amines and alcohol

Tags: solubility

Why are alcohols more water soluble than amines for similar molecular weight.
I know this is a duplicate question . The reason i posted it again was that on the original question i posted my answer and requested others to correct me if i am wrong so that i could deeply understand the concept. So I am posting my answer here again please comment on it.

Comment: I think it may be due to van der waals force (v.w.f). For both alcohols and amines the v.w.f acting between them and water molecules is keesom force i.e. dipole dipole interaction. In such case v.w.f is directly proportional to molecular mass , but if the molecular mass is also same then v.w.f is directly proportional to surface area of molecule which is inversely proportional to branching. Hence since amines have more branching than alcohol they have less surface area and hence less van der waals force. Due to weaker v.w.f amines are less soluble than alcohol.
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If respected people have the time to close my question could they please get some time to solve my query

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Why are alcohols more water doluble than amines for similar molecular weight?